# How to inject/pass attributes to nested elements

Tags: reactjs

I have the following component hierarchy:

```
<Form>
  <div>
     <Label>
      <Input name="first_name" />
     </Label>
  </div>
  <Label>
    <Input name="first_name" />
  </Label>
</Form
```

I would like to implement the following behaviors:

1. All `<Form>` components should implement a behavior that will `autofocus` the first `<Input>`, without the `<Input>` having to specify this each time again and again. Using the `autofocus` manually in every `<Form>` is prone to error, and developers tend to forget it. 
   As for now, I've decided using a code like this inside `<Form>` component:

   ```
   componentDidMount() {
     $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)).find('input:first:visible').focus()
   }
   ```
2. `<Label>` elements should have a `for`/`htmlFor` + `<Input>` attribute that matches the `<Input>` `id` inside the `<Label>` without the developer having to specify it manually each time. I am considering using a recursive `cloneElement` and injecting the `for` and `id` attributes but this sounds too cumbersome and not elegant.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

So I think we can accomplish what you're looking for by creating a few custom components: `Form` and `FormGroup`.

`Form` will be responsible for setting a prop on the `FormGroup` specifying whether or not it should be focused (I'm assuming that all of `Form`'s children are `FormGroup` instances):

```
class Form extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (el, i) => {
      const focused = i === 0;
      return React.cloneElement(el, { focused });
    });

    return <form>{children}</form>;
  }
}
```

And our `FormGroup` component has a few responsibilities.

1. It needs to focus the input element when appropriate
2. It needs to automatically set the `htmlFor` attribute for the label element

This code is a bit more involved:

```
class FormGroup extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let input = null;
    let label = null;

    // Get references to the input and label elements
    React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, el => {
      switch (el.type) {
        case 'input':
          input = el;
          return;
        case 'label':
          label = el;
          return;
      }
    });

    if (input === null || label === null) {
       throw new Error('FormGroup must be used with and input and label element');
    }

    // Augment: add the htmlFor and autoFocus attributes
    label = React.cloneElement(label, { htmlFor: input.props.id });
    input = React.cloneElement(input, { autoFocus: this.props.focused });

    // Render our augmented instances
    return <div>{label}{input}</div>;
  }
}
```

Now that we have our building blocks, we can create forms with the desired behavior:

```
<Form>
  <FormGroup>
    <label>First Label</label>
    <input id="first" type="text" />
  </FormGroup>
  <FormGroup>
    <label>Second Label</label>
    <input id="second" type="text" />
  </FormGroup>
</Form>
```

For this form, the `#first` input would be focused and each label element would have the correct `for` attributes.

Hopefully this will get you on the right track. Here's a webpackbin of this setup: http://www.webpackbin.com/VJVY1a7Tg

Comment: Hi @calvin. Thanks for the great answer. I think one of the difficulties I'm encountering is when the children hierarchy is nested. For example: one form might contain a div as a child of the <Form> and nest inside the FormGroup

Comment: That should still work as long as you make a custom component that eventually passes the "focused" property to the FormGroup component.

Comment: Edited my nesting example in the question. We currently have some forms with nested `<FormGroup>` alike components inside `<div>`s and some which aren't nested